Quickly finding $(-M)^{ATH}$ from $M+A+T+H=10$, $M-A+T+H=6$, $M+A-T+H=4$, $M+A+T-H=2$
I found this question on social media, from a math account I follow.
$$\begin{align}
M+A+T+H &=10 \\
M-A+T+H &=\;6 \\
M+A-T+H &=\;4 \\
M+A+T-H &=\;2 \\
(-M)^{ATH} &=\;\text{??}
\end{align}$$
To solve this I set up an augmented matrix that looked like:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 10 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 6 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 4 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
I proceeded with Gaussian Elimination and cleaned it up nicely after doing $R_2-R_1$, $R_3-R_1$, and $R_4-R_1$.
I ended up with
$$
M=1 \\ A=2 \\ T=3 \\ H=4 \\ \Rightarrow (-M)^{ATH}=(-1)^{(2\cdot 3\cdot 4)}=1
$$
My question is:

What is a more efficient way of solving this?

I instantly went to Gaussian Elimination, but I feel that setting up a matrix is a bit overkill for a brain teaser on Instagram.
I realize we only need to figure out if the product $ATH$ is odd or even (meaning we only need to know if one of $A$,$T$, or $H$ is odd), but I can’t think of any way to determine that.

Note that the left-hand side second equation comes from the first by subtracting $2A$, while the right-hand side decreases by $4$; thus, $2A=4$. Etc.

Label the equations $1,2,3,4$. Then find what $1-4$, $1-3$, $1-2$ give you.

$$\begin{align}
M+A+T+H &=10 \tag1\\
M-A+T+H &=\;6 \tag2\\
M+A-T+H &=\;4 \tag3\\
M+A+T-H &=\;2 \tag4\\
\end{align}$$
Then the symmetry of the coefficients of the variables in each equation suggests pairwise subtraction of the equations. In particular, $(1)-(4)$ gives $2H = 8$, $(1)-(3)$ gives $2T = 6$, $(1)-(2)$ gives $2A = 4$. With the values of each of these variables, one can substitute into $(1)$ to find $M$.

Yes. Let $L_{i}$ denote the $i$-th equation (counted from bottom to top). Notice that:
$L_{2}=L_{1}-2A$
$L_{3}=L_{1}-2T$
$L_{4}=L_{1}-2H$
So, it's easy to see:
$10-2A = 6$
$10-2T = 4$
$10-2H = 2$
Which gives $A=2$,$T=3$,$H=4$. Looking back to $L_{1}$, we plug our results back in to get $M=1$. So, our answer to $(-M)^{ATH}$ is $1$.

The sum of the last three equations has coefficient 1 on any of the ATH variables. This means $2=(2)+(3)+(4)-(1)= 2M$, that implies $M=1$. In particular, we are only interested in the parity of $ATH$, but $(1)-(2)$ gives $A=2$ and the result is 1.
Let me say, however, that a couple calculations will always be necessary, since the general solution in terms of constants $a,b,c,d$ on the right side is
$$ \left ( \frac{b+c+d-a}{2} \right )^{ 
\frac{(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)}{8} } $$
seems to have no reason to simplify - and it's not even well defined if the differences in the exponent are all odd and the base is negative.
